# Cannot import 'BlockBlobService' when calling a script from ML pipeline

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I have 2 scripts that use Azure ML SDK. In the main script I call the second script `connect_to_blob.py`. The `connect_to_blob.py` fails with the following error:

```
User program failed with ImportError: cannot import name 'BlockBlobService'
```

If I run the code of `connect_to_blob.py` from Jupyter Notebook in Azure VM, it works well. I assume that for some reason `azure-storage-blob` is unavailable for `connect_to_blob.py`.

Cannot understand why `azure-storage-blob` is not installed from `requirements.txt`.

**Main script (works fine):** it

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget, AmlCompute
from azureml.core.experiment import Experiment
from azureml.pipeline.core import Pipeline, PipelineData
from azureml.pipeline.steps import PythonScriptStep
from azureml.core.runconfig import RunConfiguration

print("Create workspace connection")

ws = Workspace.from_config()
source_directory = './sources'

run_config = RunConfiguration()
env = Environment.from_pip_requirements(name = "myenv",
                                        file_path = "requirements.txt")
env.docker.enabled = True
run_config.environment = env

compute_name = "aml-compute"
vm_size = "STANDARD_D1"

if compute_name in ws.compute_targets:
    compute_target = ws.compute_targets[compute_name]
    if compute_target and type(compute_target) is AmlCompute:
        print('Found compute target: ' + compute_name)

else:

    print('Creating a new compute target...')
    provisioning_config = AmlCompute.provisioning_configuration(vm_size=vm_size,
                                                                min_nodes=0,
                                                                max_nodes=4)

    compute_target = ComputeTarget.create(
        ws, compute_name, provisioning_config)

    compute_target.wait_for_completion(
        show_output=True, min_node_count=None, timeout_in_minutes=20)

    print(compute_target.status.serialize())

step1 = PythonScriptStep(name="train_connection_step",
                         script_name="connect_to_blob.py", 
                         compute_target=compute_target, 
                         source_directory=source_directory,
                         runconfig=run_config,
                         allow_reuse=True)
print("Step1 created")

steps = [step1]

pipeline1 = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=steps)
print ("Pipeline is built")

pipeline1.validate()
print("Pipeline validation complete")

pipeline_run = Experiment(ws, 'Hello_World1').submit(pipeline1, regenerate_outputs=False)
print("Pipeline is submitted for execution")
```

**connect_to_blob.py**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

blob_service_client = BlockBlobService(account_name='xxx', 
                                       account_key='yyy')

blob_names = blob_service_client.list_blobs("root_container")
```

for blob in blob_names:
    print(blob.name)

**requirements.txt**

```
azure==4.0.0
azure-common==1.1.23
azureml-core==1.0.74
azureml-dataprep-native==13.1.0
azureml-dataprep[fuse,pandas]==1.1.31
azureml-pipeline-core==1.0.74
azureml-pipeline-steps==1.0.74
azureml-pipeline==1.0.74
azureml-sdk==1.0.74
azureml-telemetry==1.0.74
azureml-train-core==1.0.74
azureml-train-restclients-hyperdrive==1.0.74
azureml-train==1.0.74
azure-storage-blob==12.0.0
joblib==0.14.0
pandas==0.25.3
python-dateutil==2.8.0 ; python_version >= '2.7'
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
requests==2.22.0
```

Answer (score 1):

azure-storage-blob 12.0.0 does not have a BlockBlobService anymore. Here is what you want to do to list blobs:

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

container_client = ContainerClient(account_url='xxx', # note this is the url and not name
                                   container_name="root_container",
                                   credential='yyy')

blob_names = container_client.list_blobs()
```

In version 12, you have `BlobServiceClient`, `ContainerClient`, `BlobClient` and `LeaseClient`. You can read about them [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob#clients).

Also, here are the [API ref docs](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0/index.html).